# How to create Table in meteor when the keys and values are comig from different collections

Tags: meteor

I am making multiple dynamic tables in meteor App.

The headers are coming from a different collection and the values are coming from different one.

The values of the table are dependent on the Template ID

```
Template.PdDisplay.CurrentProducts = productDB.find({"TEMPLATE_NAME: ActiveTempName"});
```

I want to display the values in the following format.

```
<template name="PdDisplay">>
    {{#each CurrentProducts}}

//How to fecth values here if the header is generated as given below
    {{/each}}
</template>


<template name="HeaderDisplay">>
    {{#each Headers}}
      {{this.NAME}}//Basically I have to find the values of {{this.NAME}}, It is acting as key for the table.
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to shove waaaaay too much logic into the view layer.

Instead, in the `onCreated`, make a local collection along with a `Tracker.dependency()` to keep it reactive. Then join the headers & the content together in that new local collection. Wrap the entire function in an `autorun` and make the last line `collectionDep.changed()`. Now, for headers you create a helper like:

```
function() {
  collectionDep.depend()
  return Object.keys(localCollection.findOne());

}
```

And then do your `#each` over that helper function.
Whenever either of the underlying collection cursors change, it'll recreate the local collection which will feed your template.